# Remove lines with no visible characters when reading a file

Tags: php, file

Reading the official [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), if I want to skip empty line in a txt file, I just need to call the function `file()` with `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES`. I wrote:

```
$fileArray = file($uploadDirectory . $tracklistFile_name, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

but it also shows empty lines. So, in a text like this :

```
// START OF THE DOCUMENT
aaa
bbb

ccc
ddd

// END OF THE DOCUMENT
```

In fact `sizeof($fileArray)` is 6 : it adds the empty lines between `bbb` and `ccc`, and the last one. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a load of ways you could clean up the array but I like this one:

```
$fileArray = array_values(array_filter($fileArray, "trim"));
```

Comment: Yeah this is like trim, but in fact when I browse the array I get a Notice: Undefined at the position where the empty line was before...

Comment: Iterate over the array with `foreach()` instead of a `for()` loop and you should be OK. (added extra line which should allow a `for` to work too

Comment: Yeah, I miss the array_values function! Nice one! Thanks

Comment: P.S. why do you prefeer empty at trim?

Comment: `empty()` will return true/false depending on whether the string (line) is empty. `trim()` will only ever return a trimmed string so for " " it'd return "" and we'd still have an empty line

Comment: I will man, don't worry! But using `array_filter` with `trim` get the same result...

Comment: Ah OK - it will because `trim()` returns "" which then evals to false

Answer (score 7):

`FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` really only skips empty lines. If you have spaces or tabs or other whitespace in it, [`file()`](http://php.net/file) will not consider it an empty line.

It doesn't do a `trim` before checking, it looks if `$line=="\n"` and only then considers it an empty line.

---

As alternative you could use:

```
$file = array_filter(array_map("trim", file("text.txt")), "strlen");
```

Comment: Uhm. So how can I remove whitespace? `$fileArray=array_filter($fileArray, "trim");` ?

Comment: Almost. See edit. But this will return all lines trimmed, not just for testing.

Comment: Uhm, it doenst work! If i tried to see the result with a for, when i delete the value I get an Notice: Undefined offset:

Comment: Use `print_r` to see results, not a `for` loop.